# Firefox tab group add-on with save-on-exit and suspend/hibernate (replacement for TGM)

Tags: firefox

I'm looking for a **currently maintained** Firefox add-on that provides:

- a grouping functionality with a "group tab" bar in addition to the tab bar,
- drag-and-drop of tabs between groups,
- an ability to rename tab groups,
- an ability to suspend/hibernate (unload) tab groups,
- correct session restore on browser restart, compatible with Firefox 29.

What I'm basically searching for is a replacement for the [TabGroups Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/tabgroups-manager/) add-on, which is sadly no longer maintained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I've **turned to the [community version of TabGroups Manager](https://code.google.com/p/tabgroupsmanager/)**, developed by a group of people who decided to continue the work of the original creator.

It works fine on modern Firefox versions, up to and including `37.0.1`.

Note: since Google Code is closing down, [the project URL will probably change in the near future](https://code.google.com/p/tabgroupsmanager/issues/detail?id=106&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Modified).

Answer (score 1):

You may try [TGM](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tabgroups-menu/) as a replacement for TGM. It isn't a perfect match, but it is currently maintained and provides:

- A group tab menu
- Drag and drop between groups
- Ability to rename tab groups
- Ability to close tab groups.

But there are numerous cons to it:

- In my experience, it fails when relaunching
- Cannot hibernate tab groups (but can kill them)
- It's a menu, and not a bar like in Manager
- It has a few graphical glitches, the menu icon keeps changing.